# Break in indented loop structure

Tags: loops, for-loop, break

In a loop structure such as `for`, does the `break;` "know" when it's under indentation levels?

For example:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (s = 0; s <= i; s++) {
        if (s == 7) break;
    }
}
```

Will this `break;` stop both for or just the inner one?

Thanks

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: @sll asks a valid question, but I've never seen a language with that style of syntax in which it would do anything but break the inner loop. And I've see a lot of those languages, the syntax influence of the language B is felt to this day, through C, C++, C#, D, Java, JavaScript, and more.

Comment: @schnaader: I've rolled back your edit. It's *completely* inappropriate to just assume the OP is talking about C and add that tag. The code in question could just as easily be Java, JavaScript, C#, D, or any of several others.

Comment: Please tag the Q with the programming language you are asking the Q in reference with, that way we could cite you references for *that particular* language.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't said what language you're using, but I've never seen a language with that sort of syntax that did anything other than break the inner loop (allowing the outer to continue). Still, though, you really should mention what language you're using! :-)

Many of the languages with that sort of syntax support labels and directed breaks, which can be used to break the outer loop. That usually looks like this:

```
outer: for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    inner: for (s = 0; s <= i; s++) {
        if (s == 7) break outer;
    }
}
```

(The `inner` label is optional in this case because we haven't used it for anything, I've just included it for completeness.)

That example would break both the inner *and* outer loops. It's valid in Java, JavaScript, and probably others; in C you'd need a label after the loop and (shudder) a `goto` and you'd probably be better off (arguably are always better off) just including some kind of termination condition in the outer loop's check that the inner loop sets.

Here's a live example in JavaScript (I've used smaller numbers to make it more obvious): [Without the directed break](http://jsbin.com/evinet) | [With the directed break](http://jsbin.com/evinet/2).

Also note that in these languages, indentation is completely irrelevant. This code is ***exactly*** the same your code (just markedly less readable):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
for (s = 0; s <= i; s++) {
if (s == 7) break;
}
}
```

This is also identical (and *dramatically* less readable):

```
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (s = 0; s <= i; s++) {
if (s == 7) break;
    }
        }
```

Obviously you'd never want to do that, but the point is that indentation is for people, not compilers (in languages with this style of syntax).

Answer (score 2):

It will break the inner loop only.

Refer the **[MSDN doccumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt88dxx6%28VS.80%29.aspx)**.

In loops, `break` terminates execution of the nearest enclosing `do`, `for`, or `while` statement. Control passes to the statement that follows the terminated statement, if any.

Comment: We don't know that the OP is using C, that was an invention by someone other than the OP editing the question. I don't think I'd use MSDN as a C reference anyway, but... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I saw the Q with an *C tag*, Also, I don't think there is anything wrong in that particular link on MSDN. Irrespective of the language the `break` would only terminate the inner loop.

Comment: `@AIs`: Yes, I figured you'd seen the bad tag, that's why I was telling you that the OP hadn't specified C anywhere. And agreed, I've never seen any language with that sort of syntax that did anything other than breaking the inner loop. Disagree about using MSDN for C reference, but whatever, it's not particularly important. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Indentation levels don't matter in languages that use accolades. Only the inner loop will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

It will stop just the inner one.

Answer (score 0):

Just the inner one. Break will break out of a single loop. You need extra logic to break out of nested loops completely, or else you can use return if your nested loop is encapsulated in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just the inner one. Some languages have a way to choose which to break.